# Single regular expression for two different strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a single regular expression that returns the color value and size values from the below two strings.

```
[{"id":"2","name":"Color","code":"COLOR","optionValue":{"value":"TANGERINE TANGO","priority":0,"altValue1":"ORANGE","altValue2":null}},{"id":"3","name":"Size","code":"SIZE","optionValue":{"value":"MEDIUM","priority":4,"altValue1":null,"altValue2":null}}]

[{"id":"3","name":"Size","code":"SIZE","optionValue":{"value":"MEDIUM","priority":4,"altValue1":null,"altValue2":null}},{"id":"2","name":"Color","code":"COLOR","optionValue":{"value":"PEACOCK BLUE","priority":0,"altValue1":"GREEN","altValue2":null}}]
```

Currently I have two different regexps for them respectively.

```
1) COLOR(?:.*?)value":"([^"]+)(?:.*?)SIZE(?:.*?)value":"([^"]+)"
2) SIZE(?:.*?)value":"([^"]+)(?:.*?)COLOR(?:.*?)value":"([^"]+)"
```

Is there a way I can achieve this using a single regex?

Comment: If you have JSON, why don't you use a JSON parser and traverse the result?

Comment: I could use a JSON parser, but the existing framework we have recommend the use of regex. :)

Comment: What JS framework recommends regexp usage for JSON strings? This is so unreliable ...

Comment: What a horrible framework recommends regex for parsing JSON?

Comment: The one I am using :) . Can't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Most compact way to do this in a single regex:

```
(COLOR|SIZE).*?value":"([^"]+).*?(?!\1)(?:COLOR|SIZE).*?value":"([^"]+)"
```

I might agree with @stribizhev and @Sirko about parsing the JSON, but I can see if you just need to get a quick-and-dirty job done, then a regex is sometimes useful.

### Explanation:

You can use **alternation**, **capturing**, **lookahead assertions**, and **backreferencing**.

First, let's simplify your regex by removing unnecessary non-capturing groups, `(?:...)`:

```
COLOR.*?value":"([^"]+).*?SIZE.*?value":"([^"]+)"
SIZE.*?value":"([^"]+).*?COLOR.*?value":"([^"]+)"
```

Now, here's what gets you halfway (similar to @MarcosPerezGude's suggestion):

```
(?:COLOR|SIZE).*?value":"([^"]+).*?(?:COLOR|SIZE).*?value":"([^"]+)"
^^^     ^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^^^    ^
```

But the problem with this is it accepts `COLOR` `COLOR` and `SIZE` `SIZE`. Here's how to get around that:

```
(  COLOR|SIZE).*?value":"([^"]+).*?(?!\1)(?:COLOR|SIZE).*?value":"([^"]+)"
 ^^                                ^^^^^^
```

Let me explain this. The `\1` is a **backreference** to whatever's captured in the first capturing group. Which in our case is now `COLOR` or `SIZE` because we've removed the non-capturing-ness. The `(?!\1)` is a **negative lookahead assertion** that says, "As long as what comes next isn't `\1`..." Therefore if the captured string was `COLOR`, the second half must be `SIZE`, or vice versa.

Comment: By the way, there is no way to do this in a single regex with _only_ the two capturing groups you desire. Alternation duplicates the capturing groups as you noticed with @JaggenSWE's suggestion. Backreferencing is the only other way to "remember" whether the first word was `COLOR` or `SIZE`, and anything requiring memory without alternation requires a capturing group—kind of like a conservation law—either the "memory" must exist in your regex (alternation, both parallel universes stored in the regex itself), or the "memory" must exist as actual memory (capturing / backreferencing).

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew !!! . Just need to use an if statement on first group's value returned.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), it is safer and is more appropriate with JSON strings:

```js
var strings = ['[{"id":"2","name":"Color","code":"COLOR","optionValue":{"value":"TANGERINE TANGO","priority":0,"altValue1":"ORANGE","altValue2":null}},{"id":"3","name":"Size","code":"SIZE","optionValue":{"value":"MEDIUM","priority":4,"altValue1":null,"altValue2":null}}]', '[{"id":"3","name":"Size","code":"SIZE","optionValue":{"value":"MEDIUM","priority":4,"altValue1":null,"altValue2":null}},{"id":"2","name":"Color","code":"COLOR","optionValue":{"value":"PEACOCK BLUE","priority":0,"altValue1":"GREEN","altValue2":null}}]'];

var cnt = 0;
strings.forEach(function(str) {
   var array = JSON.parse(str);
   cnt += 1;
   document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += "<b>Match " + cnt + "</b><br/>";
   array.forEach(function(object) {
     document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += object.optionValue.value + "<br/>";
   });
});
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

You can declare an array and `push` the results you get into the array for later use.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the OR operator

```
 ([size|color](?:.*?))
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to have it select between two alternatives like this:

```
COLOR(?:.*?)value":"([^"]+)(?:.*?)SIZE(?:.*?)value":"([^"]+)|SIZE(?:.*?)value":"([^"]+)(?:.*?)COLOR(?:.*?)value":"([^"]+)
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried this regex. It returns 4 groups, but I need only 2 to be returned. And it also confuses in choosing which group to pick